# Convolution and integrating over G(t)

Tags: statistics, integration, convolution

I'm struggling with the following expression in a statistics script:
$$H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-t) dG(t)$$
What does the dG(t) mean exactly? I've never seen that notation before.

*Background:* Random variables **X**, **Y** with CDFs **F** and **G**, we want to calculate **H** which is the CDF of (**X** + **Y**)

Comment: $dG(t)$ is the differential of $G(t)$; in other words, $dG(t)=\frac{dG(t)}{dt}dt$, where $\frac{dG(t)}{dt}=g(t)$, i.e. the probability distribution function of $Y$.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks.

Comment: I wrote some some details in the answer below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One remark on notation. Let $X$ and $Y$ be indep. r.v. with prob. distributions $f_X$ and $g_Y$. The r.v. $Z=X+Y$ has the following cumulative probability distribution.

$F_Z(z):=P(Z\leq z)=P(X+Y\leq z)=\int_{x+y\leq z} f_y(y)f_X(x)dxdy=$

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_Y(z-x)dF_X(x)$,

i.e. the formula in your question, where $F_Y(z-x)=P(Y\leq z-x)=\int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f_Y(y)dy$.

To obtain the prob. distribution $f_Z$ of $Z$ one needs to  derive w.r.t $z$  obtaining the convolution

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)dx $$